# What is the PHP analogue of the md5 function in Perl?

Tags: php, perl

I have a Perl script and I need to convert it to PHP.
What is PHP analogue of the `md5` function in Perl?

Perl script:

```
$hash  = md5($str1, $str2);
```

PHP script:

```
 $hash  = md5($str1.$str2);
```

I have different values in `$hash`.
How I can get same value of `$hash` in PHP?

Thx.

Comment: Is it the correct Perl code? Seems you are using the `add` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the perl version you are using outputs in binary format:

http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html

```
md5($data,...)
```

> This function will concatenate all arguments, calculate the MD5 digest
>   of this "message", and return it in binary form. The returned string
>   will be 16 bytes long.

Try this in PHP:

```
$hash  = md5($str1.$str2, true);
```

See the php [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) for details.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2212689/3166303 Make sure your strings are in fact identical before you hash

Comment: Yes, input data was a different.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply

```
$hash  = md5($str1.$str2, true);
```

You claim it's not equivalent, but the following shows it is:

```
$ cat x.pl
use Digest::MD5 qw( md5 );

my $str1 = join '', map chr, 0x00..0x7F;
my $str2 = join '', map chr, 0x80..0xFF;

print md5($str1, $str2);

$ perl x.pl | od -t x1
0000000 e2 c8 65 db 41 62 be d9 63 bf aa 9e f6 ac 18 f0
0000020
```

```
$ cat x.php
<?php

$str1 = join('', array_map("chr", range(0x00, 0x7F)));
$str2 = join('', array_map("chr", range(0x80, 0xFF)));

echo md5($str1.$str2, true);

?>

$ php x.php | od -t x1
0000000 e2 c8 65 db 41 62 be d9 63 bf aa 9e f6 ac 18 f0
0000020
```

```
$ diff -q <( perl x.pl ) <( php x.php ) && echo identical || echo different
identical
```